# Slow performance by PHP directory operations on virtual machine (Ubuntu libvirt)

Tags: ubuntu, performance, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

Some days ago I installed an Ubuntu server and two running virtual machines with libvirt.
Everything works fine except one performance problem.

Everytime when I call a PHP script with directory operations the operations are very slow and not performant.
Here is an example: http://zother.white-tiger.ch/
And here you see an example without a directory operation and how fast it is: http://michaeltanner.ch/

It's all on the same virtual server.
The virtual machine uses 6 cores (8 are available) and 7500 megabytes RAM (8 Gigabyte are available). The disk image format is qcow2.

How can I improve the performance?

**UPDATE**
Here is the source code of the directory listing. Before reading I have to say that the script is really old and today I wouldn't code it in that way ;)
On my server before (not virtual, on the same dedicated like now) the script didn't have to load as long as on the virtual server.

Here you can see the code: http://fixee.org/paste/yi2fmb2/

**UPDATE SOLVED**
Ok I got it. My damn source code sucks and the following command resulted in a loop until max time specified in php.ini.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://list.white-tiger.ch/i.php?vers='.$vers) ?>
```

So it's now solved with removing the command. Anyway it's really dumb to read this url. The requested url even doesn't exist. My fault, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. My damn source code sucks and the following command resulted in a loop until max time specified in php.ini.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://list.white-tiger.ch/i.php?vers='.$vers) ?>
```

So it's now solved with removing the command. Anyway it's really dumb to read this url. The requested url even doesn't exist. My fault, sorry.